# Creating 3 tabs using MVVMCross for both Xamarin.android and Xamarin.ios application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, tabs, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am creating a mobile application using MVVMCross and xamarin for both android and ios devices.

In my application I want to create 3 tabs on a screen where each of the tabs are editable.
Can anyone please help me with some example where MVVMCross is used targeting both xamarin.andriod and xamarin.ios applications.

Many Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/klzig/CycleTrip 
Is a really good, starting project to give you a basic understanding, be aware that it's written using 5.7 though.

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross 
Also has a mix of different projects with the Playground and TestProjects folders.
And finally
https://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/
https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross

Comment: Thanks for the links.

Comment: Hi is there any example where Mvvmcross is used with Toolbar in andriod having tabs because the Cycletrip example doesn't use tabs for android and N+1 example is quite old as MvxTabActivity is deprecated now.